# whether a ray can presented as a union of open rays

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $[2, \infty) \subset \mathbb{Q} $. Can we represent $[2,\infty)$ as a union of open rays in $\mathbb{Q}$: That is, can we have

$$ (2, \infty) = \bigcup_{x > 2} [x, \infty) $$

???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $2 \notin (x, \infty)$ for any $x > 2$, the union
$$\bigcup_{x > 2} (x, \infty)$$
does not include $2$.

Note than even if $(x, \infty)$ is replaced by $[x, \infty)$, the statement does not hold by the same argument.

Comment: what if we replace $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $[2, \infty) \subset \mathbb{Q}$? Is $\mathbb{Q}$ the set of rational numbers? If so why would $[2, \infty) \subset \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Or do you indeed mean $[2, \infty) = \bigcup_{x > 2, x \in \mathbb{Q}} (x, \infty)$?

Comment: yeah this is what I mean

Comment: Not true either. It is even a (improper) subset of $\cup_{x > 2} (x, \infty)$ which does not include $2$.

Comment: Usually the problem appears at the end-points. You just check whether the 2 sets include/exclude the same set of accumulation points.

Comment: but isnt $$(2, \infty) = \bigcup_{n} [2 + \frac{1}{n}, \infty) $$?

Comment: Yes it is. Indeed $\cup_{x>2,x \in \mathbb{Q}} (x, \infty) = \cup_{x>2,x \in \mathbb{Q}} [x, \infty) = (2, \infty) \subsetneq [2, \infty)$